# dataTable search box only manually input to filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, datatable

My problem is that I want to set the default value of the search box and to filter according to the conditions which I setted when I Initialize the page.
 $("#table_id_filter input").val("man"); //set the default value of the search box

```js
 $("#table_id_filter input").val("man"); //set the default value of the search box
```

But it does't work,I must click the search box and do someting(for example add a space),then it can filter.

I use the  .focus()  function to make the input be focused when the page load, and it works,but the fifter don't excute, I must to excute one keyEvent then it can filter.I want to know if I can invoke the filter function again when the input has be focused.

If I want to finish this function,how? Can you helo me? Thank you!

Comment: Can you please show some code?

Comment: Just `trigger focus` on your `searchbox` on `page load`

Comment: When page load I focus the search box use these code :$("#table_id_filter input").attr("autofocus", "autofocus"); but it does't work.it can't filter

Answer (score 0):

As "Guruprasad Rao" Suggested in the comments trigger focus on page load, see code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form>
   First name: <input type="text" name="fname" autofocus><br>
   Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The autofocus attribute of the input tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.</p>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Heres a working example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Pihw47MFzIVbBP9NH0VL?p=preview

Comment: I use the  .focus()  function to make the input be focused, and it works,but the fifter don't excute, I must to excute one keyEvent then it can filter.I want to know if I can invoke the filter function again when the input has be focused.

Comment: @web_wolf have you tried the onchange event? You can assign a text field the onChange event and run a function when a change occurs on the text field.